# How can I measure elapsed time between the press of buttons in python with tkinter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, stopwatch

I'm very new to python and I'm trying to do a little project for myself, but I don't understand how to use the initial time variable from the start function in the stop function where I can do math with it. This is my code currently:

```
import time
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox

top = Tkinter.Tk()

def start_time():
   tkMessageBox.showinfo("Timer", "The timer will now begin")
   initial = time.time()
   return initial

def stop_time(initial):
   final = time.time()
   tkMessageBox.showinfo("Timer", final - initial)

Start = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Start", command = start_time)
Stop = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Stop", command = stop_time)
Start.pack()
Stop.pack()
top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

Your functions need to agree on a common place for shared data. For this simple example, the module's global namespace is a good choice. All you need to do is add `global initial` to the functions that update it. For larger projects you may move to objects that hold the variables and the functions that update it, but this is fine for your goals.

```
import time
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox

initial = 0

top = Tkinter.Tk()

def start_time():
   global initial
   tkMessageBox.showinfo("Timer", "The timer will now begin")
   initial = time.time()
   return initial

def stop_time():
   # you could check for initial == 0 and display an error
   final = time.time()
   tkMessageBox.showinfo("Timer", final - initial)

Start = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Start", command = start_time)
Stop = Tkinter.Button(top, text ="Stop", command = stop_time)
Start.pack()
Stop.pack()
top.mainloop()
```